# hp laserjet p2035 won't print second page of booklets

Tags: windows, printing, hp-laserjet, duplex, wordperfect

I bought WordPerfect X5 and installed it on both of my computers.  The tower was running Windows XP and my laptop has Windows 7.

Prior to X5 I was using WordPerfect 11 on both my tower and laptop computers and booklets would print for me.

Now, neither printer will print more than the first side of the booklets.

I uninstalled X5 on the tower and reinstalled WordPerfect 11....no luck.
I also reinstalled both printer drivers....no luck.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

1. On your PC: Check the options of the printer in the control panel and the options in WordPerfect.
2. On the printer: Check the settings and let it do it's maintenance routine.

It sounds like you have this problem on both PCs, then it is more likely to be the printer.

Contact the Support Center of HP and WordPerfect if you can't resolve this yourself...